# How to port Rails Rake task output called via cron task to Rails production server output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unix, logging, cron, stdout

I have a series of cron jobs in crontab. The cron jobs call Rake tasks via the following format:

```
* * * * * /bin/sh -l -c 'cd /app && bundle exec rake foo:bar[baz] >> /var/log/foobar_sync.log 2>&1'
```

I thought I was redirecting their output (via `puts`) to STDOUT via 2>&1, but I suppose I am approaching the issue incorrectly.

How can I redirect the output of these Rake tasks into the Rails server log output, along with the Rails server logs themselves, so their output can be seen alongside Rails server output?

Comment: Does the rake task use the `Rails.logger` commands?

Comment: @nathanvda The rake task uses `puts`, which I assumed defaulted to the environment's set Rails.logger.

Comment: Nope. `puts` just outputs to the console (aka STDOUT), in your case it seems you would prefer to use `Rails.logger` instead? Most of the times in my rake files I add a method that does both (or checks a flag, so that I can choose, because when manually running I prefer to see the `puts` insteading of tailing my rails log, but pick your flavour).

Comment: @nathanvda Tried replacing all calls to `puts` with calls to `Rails.logger.debug` and getting the same behavior. My log settings in environments/production.rb is set to the following:
`config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`. I wonder if the problem is that Rails server is running in its own separate instance, therefore has its own instance of STDOUT.

Comment: Ow your rails instance logs to STDOUT? So when you mean "the Rails server log output" you actually want the stdout of one process to be concatenated/joined with that from another process? Afaik that is not possible, but I am not sure. Maybe you should rephrase your question to make this more obvious. Is logging to file out of the question? Because it is (obviously) easier to let multiple process log in the same file.

Comment: @nathanvda The developer before me set it to STDOUT, for reasons which I'm not sure of, but I do know he was a smart guy. I think you're right... it's not possible to "attach" or "inject" to another process's STDOUT.

I think I might simply bypass calling the Rake task altogether and simply create a Route which simply bypasses the Task and calls the same method which the Task calls. That way it will run in the same process as Rails server and log the output to Rails' own STDOUT.

Comment: @nathanvda Dug in a little more and found a solution. Thanks for your suggestions. Answered below.

Comment: Perhaps calling it from [arask](https://github.com/Ebbe/arask)? It will run the code "inside" rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that there is no way (aside from hacking Linux, perhaps) to integrate the STDOUT of a Rake task into the STDOUT of a Rails server, due to the simple nature of the OS architecture.

I solved my issue by doing the following:

1. Call the target method of the Rake task in a Rails controller.
2. Call the method of the Rails controller via a Rails route.
3. Call the Rails route via a `curl` in crontab.

Now the output of the method (in my case, a sync task for which I created an ActiveJob) is visible in the STDOUT of the Rails server.